# panda Excel Writer is not working correctly

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe

I'm writing my Dataframe into excel file using ExcelWriter but I notice that their missing data have been not written. 
is it a bug in the ExcelWriter ? or I'm making a mistake

```
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('test_output3.xlsx')
for sheet in sheets:
    _df=df[df['Sheet']==sheet].drop(columns=['Sheet'])
    _df.to_excel(writer,sheet)
writer.save()
```

Here how my data it is in dataframe:
[image: In DataFrame]
.....
[image: In DataFrame]

and here how it is in Excel
[image: In Excel]

Answer (score 0):

I reinstall my 'openpyxl' library and its working now!